# What is the difference between the SIGHUP generated by typing "exit" in the SSH shell terminal vs clicking the "X" button in the PuTTY window?

Tags: linux, kill, background-process, nohup, signals

Referring to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/769824/how-to-use-nohup-to-continue-to-run-a-command-after-the-user-logout), I am trying to use `nohup <command> <arg> &` to continue to run a command in the background after I logout from the SSH shell terminal. However, the background process terminates immediately when I logout from the shell terminal, even though I have used `nohup ... &`.

After further testing, I found that the background process will only terminate when I logout by clicking the `X` button in the PuTTY window. If I logout from the PuTTY window by typing `exit` in the SSH shell terminal, the background process will continue to run in the background.

Why the background process behaves differently when I logout using these 2 methods?

What is the difference between the SIGHUP generated by typing `exit` in the SSH shell terminal vs clicking the `X` button in the PuTTY window?

Comment: It depends on what your command *does* (in a couple of quick checks, neither case stops).  By knowing more about the command, someone might point out a reason.